# How to search something in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Hello I have a `NSMutableArray` like this

```
Contactarray (

{

   "firstNAme"="name1"
   "lastName"="name2"
   "phoneNumber"="12345678902";
}

{

   "firstNAme"="name1"
   "lastName"="name2"
   "phoneNumber"="12345678902";
}
```

I want to search the person when I type the person name in my `UITextField`. Then the filtered `UItableView` should be loaded. This `NSMutableArray` contains `NSMutableDictionaries`.

How can I find the matching object from these objects?

Lets say I want to search all name1 people. Then I want to find all the objects containing "name1" and those objects should fill to another array to load the `UITableview`

Please help me.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is my contacts array

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7b601f70>(
firstname = Kate;
lastName = Bell;
phone = "(415) 555-3695";
userimg = "<UIImage: 0x7b67b3a0>";
};

{
firstname = Kate;
lastName = Bell;
phone = "(415) 555-3695";
userimg = "<UIImage: 0x7b67b3a0>";
},
```

This is my code for search

`

```
 [playlistArray removeAllObjects];
 NSArray *contacts=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutArraySearchContacts];
 NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname = %@ OR lastName = %@",currentSrchStr,currentSrchStr];
 playlistArray=[contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playlistsLoaded) withObject:nil];
```

`

But my playlistArray is empty.

`

```
(lldb) po playlistArray
<__NSArrayI 0x7b74adf0>(

)
```

`

What is the wrong I have done here?

Comment: Using `NSPredicate`, google it, you will find easy solution.,

Comment: yeas. for (int i=0; i<[mutArraySearchContacts count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *objectDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
      NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectDict.firstname contains %@",currentSrchStr]; I did something like this. But Im not sure my predicate string is correct or not

Comment: Have a look at my answer, it will help you, Tested answer.

Comment: Are `Kate` and `Bell` your custom class?

Comment: No those are not custom classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate while you use `NSPredicate`. Try this.

```
NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF['firstNAme'] contains '%@' || SELF['lastName'] contains '%@'",currentSrchStr,currentSrchStr]];
NSArray *filterArray = [mutArraySearchContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];
NSLog(@"filterArray %@", filterArray);
```

**Update 1:**
Modify your predicate with `CONTAIN[C]` for case insensitive, like

```
NSPredicate * myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF['firstNAme'] CONTAINS[c] '%@' || SELF['lastName'] CONTAINS[c] '%@'",currentSrchStr,currentSrchStr]];
```

Hope this helps you !!

Comment: how can I check whether that name available in both first and last name?

Comment: Thank you somuch. And can I ignore lowercase or uppercase? Now it gives Daniel as the result if I typed D only. how can I do it with d too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` method to find all keys where the value equals `@"test"`.

In the implementation below only the first key will be found. If you need all keys where the object is `@"Test"`, do not assign `*stop`.

```
NSString *target = @"test";

NSSet *keys = [myDictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) 
{

    return (*stop = [target isEqual:obj]);

}];
```

when u get the key you can proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *contacts = ...; //your array of NSDictionary objects
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstName == %@", @"name1"]];

NSArray *filteredContacts = [contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

If you need to search with more condition, like full name:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"firstName == %@ OR lastName == %@" ,@"name1", @"name2"]];
```

Here is [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1), which illustrates more advanced features.

Comment: here is my code  NSArray *contacts=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutArraySearchContacts];
     NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = name1 OR lastName = name2"];
    playlistArray=[contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

Comment: I think your code works. Do you get the expected result?

Comment: BTW, the first name key in your dictionary is `firstNAme`, maybe you want `firstName`

Comment: No I dont get the result my array is empty. yeahh that key is "firstname" but im getting an empty array